# How to match checking predecessor first in Eclipse regex search?

Tags: java, regex, string, eclipse

I would like to prepare a pattern that will find out the word:

```
footer
```

I would like cover the following cases:

- `footer` starts from other character than `-`
- `footer` might be the first substring in line

Below regex example does not work as I thought:

```
(?:[^-]|^)footer
```

same for that one:

```
(?:[^-]footer|^footer)
```

Could somebody clarify why above examples does not solves the problem and provide an example pattern that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?:[^-]|^)footer` pattern matches any char but `-` or start of string, and then matches `footer`. So, the char matched with `[^-]` will be part of the match. Same is with `(?:[^-]footer|^footer)`.

You may use a `(?<!-)` [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!-)footer
```

or with a word boundary to match as a whole word

```
\b(?<!-)footer\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6kZmfq/1).

The `(?<!-)` will fail the match if there is a `-` immediately to the left of the current location.

Comment: `(?<!-)footer` solves the problem, but also could You tell me what is the cause that this pattern `(?:[^-]|^)footer` does not match footer when the line looks for example like that `footer`?

Comment: @J3W That is rather weird, because `[^-]` matches line breaks and when a `footer` is at the start of a line `(?:[^-]|^)footer` should match `\nfooter`. No idea then, probably it is the issue with how Eclipse regex engine deal with multiline text. Still, try to add `(?m)` at the start of the pattern to make sure `^` matches the start of the line positions.

Comment: tried with multiline mode but with same effect, thank you for comment, so the current conclusion is it is a bug (unless somewhere is specifically stated that ^ is processed specifically :) )